# jQuery animation - content gets stuck in IE 7, 8, 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, menu

I am using jQuery and jQuery-UI to make a navigation menu for a project I am working on and am having a strange issue with the jQuery animation in Internet Explorer. The code finds a tag that is nested i na specific order (li ul li a OR li ul li h3) and adds a class to the tag, which is used to toggle the content visibility. The jQuery code I am using can be seen here:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.menuLocator = function (options1) {
    var defaults = {

    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options1);

    return this.each(function () {
        var menu = this;
        var basePath = window.location.href.split(window.location.host)[1];
        var paths = basePath.split('.html').join('').split('/');
        for (var i = 1; i != paths.length; i++) {
            $(menu).find('a[href$="' + paths[i] + '"]').addClass('active').addClass('level_' + i).parent().find('ul:first').addClass('active');
            $('a.active').find('.has_children:first').addClass('open');
        }
        $(menu).find('li ul').parent().find('a:first').append('<span class="has_children"><span class="icon"></span></span>');

for (var i = 1; i != paths.length; i++) {
            $(menu).find('a[href$="' + paths[i] + '"]').addClass('active').addClass('level_' + i).parent().find('li h3').addClass('active');
            $('h3.active').find('.has_children').addClass('open');
        }


        $(menu).find('li ul').parent().find('h3').append('<span class="has_children"><span class="icon"></span></span>');


        $(menu).find('.has_children').toggle(

        function () {
            var is_old_ie = false;
            var speed = 200;

            if($.browser.msie){
                is_old_ie = true;
            }

            if(is_old_ie){
                speed = 1;
            }

            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle(speed);
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        },

        function () {
            var is_old_ie = false;
            var speed = 200;

            if($.browser.msie){
                is_old_ie = true;
            }

            if(is_old_ie){
                speed = 1;
            }

            $(this).prevAll(":has(.active):first").removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle(speed);
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

In Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera, everything works fine. But in IE (7, 8, 9) I get the following bug:

The navigation displays fine initially:

[image: Initial navigation]

When a user clicks the icons, each section expands to show sub-navigation:

[image: Opening section] [image: Opening another section]

However, when you close the section immediately above an open section, the content does not shift up to match the menu.

[image: Content shifts]

If you open and close the section above, it will continue to push content down, but won't push it up.

[image: Pushing continues]

Closing and re-opening a sub-menu will cause the content to reset. Opening items in the sub-menus cause the content to shift down and up as expected.

The menu is created using the following HTML:

```
<!-- Left zone -->
<div class = "zoneLeft" style = "float: left;" >
<div class = "leftColumn" >

<ul class = "menu" >
    <li>
        <a> In This Section < /a>
        <ul id="menuElem">
            <li><a href="/Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Open - Government / Your - Rights - to - an - Open - and - Accountable - Government " >Your Rights to an Open and Accountable Government</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Related</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=" / About - AG / Contact ">Contact</a></li><li><a href=" / Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Sign - Up - For - Updates - to - ohio - s - Sunshine - Laws ">Sign Up For Updates to Ohio&#39;s Sunshine Laws</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / FAQ / Sunshine - laws - FAQs ">Sunshine Laws FAQs</a></li><li><a href=" / Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Sunshine - Laws - Publication - Request - Form ">Sunshine Laws Publication Request Form</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Sunshine - Law - Training ">Sunshine Laws Training</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Publications</a>
        <ul id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder1_pageplaceholder1_lt_zoneLeft_TagDisplayPublications_BListTagged " class="subCMSListMenuUL ">
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications -for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / 2012 - Sunshine - Laws - Manual.aspx ">2012 Sunshine Laws Manual</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications - for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Appendix - A - % e2 % 80 % 93 - Statutes - Public - Records, - Open - Meeting.aspx ">Appendix A – Statutes: Public Records, Open Meetings &amp; Personal Information Systems Act</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications - for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Appendix - B - % e2 % 80 % 93 - Statutory - Excepting - Records - from - the.aspx">Appendix B – Statutory Excepting Records from the Ohio Public Records Act or Declaring Records</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications - for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Appendix - C - % e2 % 80 % 93 - Ohio - Attorney - General - Opinions - Interp.aspx ">Appendix C – Ohio Attorney General Opinions Interpreting Ohio’s Public Records Act</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications - for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Appendix - D - % e2 % 80 % 93 - Ohio - Attorney - General - Opinions - Interp.aspx ">Appendix D – Ohio Attorney General Opinions Interpreting Ohio’s Open Meetings Act</a></li>
            <li><a href=" / Files / Publications / Publications - for -Legal / Sunshine - Laws / Model - Public - Records - Policy.aspx ">Model Public Records Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you just use the Accordion feature of jQuery UI?

Comment: The basic implementation was provided by the designers we were working with. For lack of a better solution I might try to implement the navigation using an Accordion. The CMS we're using limits some functionality, but hopefully it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I post my solution to this problem, let me preface it by saying that I am aware that this is a terrible way of fixing this bug. The issue only occurs on a couple pages, and we have decided to fix it in post-production. Hopefully this will not be the final solution.

That being said, I fixed the animation issue by triggering click events when a panel is closed. Since the content in a panel resets when it is closed and re-opened, I used the following code to trigger two click events (close/re-open) on each section following the active section. In IE, the animation duration is set to 0 ms anyways, so this content reset is not visible to the user. Additionally, there is a minimal performance loss, since if the panels are open the content has already been rendered and does not need to be reloaded.

```
$(menu).find('.has_children').toggle(

        function() {
            var speed = 200;

            if ($.browser.msie) {
                speed = 0;
            }

            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle(speed);
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        },

        function() {
            var speed = 200;

            if ($.browser.msie) {
                speed = 0;
            }

            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle(speed);
            $(this).toggleClass('open');

            /* IE7 Nav Push Bug Fix */
            if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version.slice(0,1) == "7" ) {
                $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().children('a').children().children().trigger('click');
                $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().children('a').children().children().trigger('click');
            }
            /* End */
        });
```